Old project connection string using metadata tag, and providerName, is this needed?
I've started working on an older C# API application (over 10+ years when it was created), it has recently been updated by another dev somewhat to use .NET framework 4.8 with EF 6 (but still with the old connection string):
public partial APIEntities : DbContext
{
    public APIEntities()
            : base("name=APIEntitiesConnection")
    {
    }
    
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }
    
    public virtual DbSet<Object1> List1 { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Object2> List2 { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Object3> List3 { get; set; }
    //etc...
}

The connection string in the config is:
<add name="APIEntitiesConnection" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/DB_Api.csdl|res://*/DB_Api.ssdl|res://*/DB_Api.msl;
                       provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
                       provider connection string=&quot;data source=ServerName;
                       initial catalog=DB_Api;persist security info=True;
                       user id=userName;password=password; 
                       MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

My question is why is this connection string so long? And there is a connection string inside a connection string? I haven't seen anything like this before with the metadata and provider tags, are they all needed?
I found some stuff online, but the questions are over 10+ years ago - like Code-First Migrations for multiple databases? which talks about the difference between a System.Data.EntityClient instead of System.Data.SqlClient, so the connection string I provided is an Entity Framework one, which is needed to do al the EF magic, but nowadays are all these extra tags are needed?
I tried removing them and got errors about metadata tag needed, didn't provide providerName tag etc...
I was hoping that because this project has been updated to EF6, all of these extra tags that were needed back in the day wont be needed now?
So I could just use something like:
 "Server=ServerName;Database=DataBaseName;User Id=userId;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"

but when I tried this I got an error about metadata tags being needed for model/data first.

System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.UnintentionalCodeFirstException: 'The context is being used in Code First mode with code that was generated from an EDMX file for either Database First or Model First development.  This will not work correctly. To fix this problem do not remove the line of code that throws this exception. If you wish to use Database First or Model First, then make sure that the Entity Framework connection string is included in the app.config or web.config of the start-up project. If you are creating your own DbConnection, then make sure that it is an EntityConnection and not some other type of DbConnection, and that you pass it to one of the base DbContext constructors that take a DbConnection. To learn more about Code First, Database First, and Model First see the Entity Framework documentation here: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=394715'

According to the above error message I should add code into the start-up project, but this is an old project and I'm not sure what template the developer used but there is no startUp file.
Any ideas on how I can tidy up that large connection string into something more straight forward? Or would it require a re-design of the .edmx file etc??
Thank you for any response

@Stuartd heres an example of my connection string in .Net 8 - "Server=localhost;Initial Catalog=db-name;User ID=userid;Password=password;TrustServerCertificate=False;Encrypt=True" and as you say no, I don't need to provide those. I assume you use ADO.net which will require those. Here is a link describing the ADO.net connection string: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/connection-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN

It's all explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/configuring/connection-strings#databasemodel-first-with-connection-string-in-appconfigwebconfig-file

Hey, thanks for the reply people. I will read both links. Thank you, I have a question though please... you said I assume I use ADO.net which will mean I need the extra metadata tags (which are needed to create the entity framework connection string) but I thought you can only be ADO.net or entity framework? why both? forgive me if im wrong but ADO.net is for for grain SQL control, while entity framework is an ORM that is a layer that sits ontop of the ADO.net? Is it because this project is so old that it was using both back in the day?

Maybe this explains it better. EDMX requires this large connection string that supplies both the location of the meta data and the (ADO.Net) connection string. When the first part is missing, EF will execute OnModelCreating. Either way, it's strongly recommended to get rid of the EDMX file.

Ahh ok I see... ok starting to make more sense... So I have a question then please... if the databse name was to change would this affect anything? for example currently the meta data(DbName .csdl, DbName.ssdl & DbName.msl )and the DbName.edmx file all have the same name e.g DbName (name of the db), if I was to change the dbName (say for example we created a new enviornment with a fresh back up of the current DB but named it ProductionDbName would the cdsl,ssdl & msl in the metadata and the edmx file have to be changed to reflect this new name of the actual db?

No, only the inner connection string part.
